# How to close(hide) menu on mobile when menu item is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, navbar, nav

I have a problem with my website when it is seen on mobile phone. I have one button that opens "table" with menu items. When I click on some menu item, correct page opens, but "table" with menu items is not closed. It closes only when I click on menu button again.

I tried all the solutions for similar situations that are offered here, but non of them worked for me. 
Does anyone have a clue how can I fix this? 
Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:

in head tag:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>  
<script src="js/templatemo_custom.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.lightbox.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
```

in body tag:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
          <div class="container-fluid"> 
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->           
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> 
                <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
            </div>           
            <div id="top-menu">
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse main_menu" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li><a class="show-1 templatemo_home" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".in" href="#"><span class="fa fa-home"></span>Početna</a></li>
                  <li><a class="show-1 templatemo_page3" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".in" href="#"><span class="fa fa-users"></span>Čime se bavimo</a></li>
                  <li><a class="show-1 templatemo_page5" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".in" href="#"><span class="fa fa-medkit"></span>Terapija</a></li>
                  <li><a class="show-1 templatemo_page2" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".in" href="#"><span class="fa fa-picture-o"></span>Galerija</a></li>
                  <li><a class="show-1 templatemo_page4" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".in" href="#"><span class="fa fa-envelope"></span>Kontakt i lokacija</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>        
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse --> 
          </div>
          <!-- /.container-fluid --> 
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use javascript for that. Try below code.

```
<script>
  function closeFunction()
  { 
     document.getElementById('bs-example-navbar-collapse-1').style.display='none';
  }
</script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
          <div class="container-fluid"> 
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->           
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> 
                <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
            </div>           
            <div id="top-menu">
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse main_menu" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li><a class="show-1 templatemo_home" onclick="closeFunction()" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".in" href="#"><span class="fa fa-home"></span>Početna</a></li>
                  <li><a class="show-1 templatemo_page3" onclick="closeFunction()" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".in" href="#"><span class="fa fa-users"></span>Čime se bavimo</a></li>
                  <li><a class="show-1 templatemo_page5"onclick="closeFunction()" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".in" href="#"><span class="fa fa-medkit"></span>Terapija</a></li>
                  <li><a class="show-1 templatemo_page2" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".in" href="#"><span class="fa fa-picture-o"></span>Galerija</a></li>
                  <li><a class="show-1 templatemo_page4" onclick="closeFunction()" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".in" href="#"><span class="fa fa-envelope"></span>Kontakt i lokacija</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>        
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse --> 
          </div>
          <!-- /.container-fluid --> 
    </nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It solved my original problem - now "table" with menu items closes on click on menu item, but after that click,  menu button doesn't work any more ("table" is opened only once, when I click for the first time on button, and when I click on menu item, "table" with menu items can't be opened any more).

Comment: try this code in same function after old script line :-   `document.getElementById('bs-example-navbar-collapse-1').style.display='block';`

Comment: Now I'm back to start - "table" with menu items is not hidden when I click on item. Plus, now when I click again on menu button, "table" is not really hidden, it only "fades" away..

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution to my problem :)

In addition to Omkar solution, there should be one more function - for button it self:

```
 <script>
  function closeFunction()
  { 
      document.getElementById('bs-example-navbar-collapse-1').style.display = "none";

  }
  function openFunction(){
    document.getElementById('bs-example-navbar-collapse-1').style.display = "initial";
  }
</script> 
     <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
          <div class="container-fluid"> 
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->           
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" onclick="openFunction()" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> 
                <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
            </div>           
            <div id="top-menu">
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse main_menu" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li><a class="show-1 templatemo_home" onclick="closeFunction()"  data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".in" href="#"><span class="fa fa-home"></span>Početna</a></li>
                  <li><a class="show-1 templatemo_page3" onclick="closeFunction()" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".in" href="#"><span class="fa fa-users"></span>Čime se bavimo</a></li>
                  <li><a class="show-1 templatemo_page5" onclick="closeFunction()" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".in" href="#"><span class="fa fa-medkit"></span>Terapija</a></li>
                  <li><a class="show-1 templatemo_page2" onclick="closeFunction()" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".in" href="#"><span class="fa fa-picture-o"></span>Galerija</a></li>
                  <li><a class="show-1 templatemo_page4" onclick="closeFunction()" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".in" href="#"><span class="fa fa-envelope"></span>Kontakt i lokacija</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>        
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse --> 
          </div>
          <!-- /.container-fluid --> 
    </nav>
```